# Winform controls not firing events - validating, validated, gotfocus

Tags: c#, winforms, events

My question is why i cannot get the events of the controls to fire.  My code is as follows:

```
    private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("WORKS"); 
    }
```

Please excuse the messagebox as i ended up creating a new form just for testing purposes.  My plan is when a user clicks onto a textbox it opens a new form as a dialog to select a date and then return to the original form.  But i cannot get the event to fire.

After reading loads of info online including: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I cannot see how it is not firing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Im new to posting on forums so please go gentle with me.

Comment: Have u written event manually by hand. or double clicked on right panel's event list? You dont need to write it manually

Comment: It has been hand written and with a previous try copied and pasted from the msdn website.

Comment: On right hand panel in event tab you will see event list. Double click on GotFocus event and write ur logic in it

Comment: are you sure you attach this event handler to your textbox's GotFocus event?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwsdtbk(v=vs.90).aspx check this to create event using designer

Comment: Rightly stated by @Selman22. As per ur requirement. You can never write any value in your textbox

Comment: @Lawrence - Is the `CausesValidation` property set to true?

Comment: The DateTimePicker control is not good enough for your requirement? And an advice, do not mess with GotFocus (particularly with actions that move the focus away like a MessageBox)

Comment: @Steve - that makes logical sense now thank you regarding gotfocus.  As it would surely loop around and once ive put the data in the textbox the gotfocus would fire again.  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Nitin - I have got it to work now with what you have mentioned.  I never attached the event to the textbox.  Great help and speed to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you didn't attach the event handler, try this on `Form Load:`

```
textBox1.GotFocus += textBox1_GotFocus;
```

If you don't see `Form_Load` event double click your form in the designer and write this code inside of it.

Comment: Great answer thank you did the trick.  But prefer the method metioned by Nitin regarding using the events tab in the properties window as its less code.

Comment: @Lawrence it is not less code.When you did that,this line added to the Form.Designer.cs automatically, there is no difference.If you go to the Form1.Designer.cs you will the code like this.